# Connect to UTF-8 MySQL Database with Grails

Tags: mysql, grails, utf-8, amazon-rds

I've been having trouble connecting a Grails application to a MySQL database hosted on Amazon's RDS. It was working fine, util I realized that users in Russia were entering Cyrillic characters into my form, which resulted in the MySQL database showing the data as ????????.

So, I've [converted the data in the database from Latin1 to UTF-8.](http://khelll.com/blog/mysql/changing-database-encoding-from-latin-to-utf8/) (why oh why isn't UTF-8 the default?)

I've added "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8" to the end of my JDBC connection string:

```
jdbc:mysql://myserver.amazonaws.com/mydatabase?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8
```

Now, when grails connects to my database, I get the error

> java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: C2ACC3AD
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:800)
>           at java.io.ObjectInputStream.(ObjectInputStream.java:297)

One possibility that I've seen described as a resolution to this with other frameworks is to have the database connection run

```
SET NAMES UTF8
```

Immediately after connecting to the database. However, I don't know how to force Grails to do this, because Grails handles its database connection process under the hood. Any ideas?

Comment: The updated JDBC URL should be all you need. It looks suspiciously like some data was serialized as an object in the database at some point, and that data is now no longer valid. Does that exception only occur for queries on a certain domain class?

Comment: YES. That was it. I had a domain class that was storing a little bit of meta-data as a serialized hash map. Once I set all the data column to null, the problem was fixed. Now I just have figure out how to repalce that metadata with something better... Thanks!

Comment: Please answer your own question then to stop it showing up as `unaswered`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, this problem was caused by a domain class that was storing a little bit of meta-data as a HashMap. This data was, in turn, serialized in the database. When the database was moved from LATIN-1 to UTF-8, this serialized data was corrupted due to the change in character encoding. When the data was accessed, the application then puked in the above described manner.

Once I manually set all the data in that column to null, the problem was fixed.

As a coding practice, its probably best to avoid the shortcut of using HashMaps in your domain objects.